# Is there any method to split the hours from hh:mm:ss format in python?

Tags: python

I am learning python.i have created a list that store multiple values in format "hh:mm:ss". now i want to split the hours part of each element of it. Please help.

Comment: Check some documentation or tutorials like [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the `split()` method for strings. A quick example:

```
eta='12:34:56' #this is a string
splitted=eta.split(':')
```

and the result (`splitted`) is the following list:

```
['12', '34', '56']
```

which you can easily access by list indexing: the hour part (`12`) will be `splitted[0]`, the minutes part (`34`) will be `splitted[1]` and the seconds part (`56`) will be `splitted[2]`.

If you have a list of hours, just iterate over such list with a for-loop and apply the `split()` method to each element of the list. Let's say our list is:

```
hoursList=['12:34:56','78:90:12']
```

you can do something like

```
for item in hoursList:
    splitted=item.split(':')
    print splitted[0]
```

and this code will print out

```
12
78
```

that is, indeed, the hours part of the strings in `hoursList`.

Comment: could you also tell me how to store it in dictionary so that i could have some "hh" as a key and the number of times it occurs as value??

Comment: The *key* value is the hour (`splitted[0]` in this case). The *value* is initialized as `1` if you meet such value for the first time (`if splitted[0] not in dictionary.keys()` or something like that) and if is already present you simply increment such value. Say hello to Charles Severance from me.

Comment: This link will also help: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
time = "hh:mm:ss".split(":")
print(time[0])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

use regex on each list element: (\d{2}):\d{2}:\d{2}